# Sharepoint Online - List sharepoint sites in a sitecollection using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

i want so list all sites in a sitecollection in sharepoint online using powershell. I am using the following script at the moment:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteUrl = “https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection” 
$username = "myusername" 
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)  
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)  
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

$rootWeb = $ctx.Web  
$sites  = $rootWeb.Webs 

$ctx.Load($rootWeb) 
$ctx.Load($sites) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

foreach($site in $sites) 
{ 
    $ctx.Load($site) 
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

    Write-Host $site.Title "-" $site.Url  
}
```

The errors look like:

```
Exception calling " executeQuery " with 0 Argument ( s) : " The remote server returned an error : ( 401 ) Unauthorized . "
Line : 16 Char: 1

The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
In Zeile:18 Zeichen:9
+ foreach($site in $sites)
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not a site collection admin.

Implement this change:

`$sites  = $rootWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser($null)`